# Expand UITextView to Full Screen when Scrolling - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I want to know how to expand the `UITextView` that I have created to the full screen when scrolling down, however, the only thing on the screen that I am using as a `UITextView` is the small paragraphs of the newspaper in this example. The UIImage and title are both not part of the `UITextView`, however, I have embedded the `UITextView`, title(`UILabel`), and `UIImage` in a scrollview. I have also disabled the scrolling for the `UITextView` itself, however, I want it so that when you scroll down for more text, the UITextView's height will expand upwards to cover the screen and you can keep scrolling for more text.

Here is a picture of what my screen looks like:

[image: screen]